# Java Algorithm for retrieving and storing user dates using Firestore database

Tags: java, android, algorithm, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to build this algorithm, what it will do is retrieve a reference (in this case a date), this date will be used to check against my firestore database to ensure that there are less than 3 employees who have booked this same date. So you will see here

> startDateReference = 202131Thursday =  Thursday, 1st of April, 2021

So I am running a loop, within this loop is a counter, this counter will take account the amount of times this reference is called in the loop. However, if it is looped 3 times the program will stop the loop, which is great, but I am unable to wrap my head around how to execute a condition if the loop has resolved as less than 3 iterations. For example, at the moment my database only has 2 of these reference stored, so I am successully able to call each iteration, but it does not take account that there is 1 more extra slot.

my code:

```
final Query query = db.collection("holidays").whereEqualTo("startDateReference",totalDateCode);
                    query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                            //creating a map to obtain information
                            Map<String, Object> test = new HashMap<>();
                            //counter
                            int counter = 0;
                            boolean flag = false;

                            //retrieve data as a hashmap document
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: queryDocumentSnapshots){
                                Note data = documentSnapshot.toObject(Note.class);
                                test.put("startDateReference", data.getStartDateReference());
                                Collection<Object> values = test.values();

                                //retrieve results as single values
                                for (Object string : values) {

                                    do {
                                        //System.out.println(string);

                                        if (string.equals("202131Thursday")) {
                                            counter++;
                                            System.out.println("Checking for holidays" + counter);

                                        } else if (counter == 3) {
                                            System.out.println("could not save data it is packed");

                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("storing details");

                                        }

                                    } while (counter == 3);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

The results i get:

```
> I/System.out: 0
>     Checking for holidays1 I/System.out: 1
>     Checking for holidays2
```

But after this last result I expect this condition to execute as seen in the else condition within my code as there is a extra space (note i have not coded in my database store function i am using just string text to see how it would work right now and the database only has 2 of the reference, there is a extra slot which i am trying to store details in):

```
System.out.println("storing details");
```

Answer (score 1):

Call another condition outside of all the loops and then after the loops have resolved you can use the counter as its final form to verify whether there is space or not using else if statements.